# What's wrong with this Java to C# conversion?

Tags: c#, java, .net, regex

i'm trying to convert the following code from Java to C#.

```
// Replace 0 0 0 0; with 0.
css = css.replaceAll(":0 0 0 0(;|})", ":0$1");
```

which I convert as ...

```
var foo = new Regex(":0 0 0 0(;|})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(foo, "XXXXXXXX");
```

This compiles but does not work when i run this against the following code...

```
foo = "a {background-position: 0 0 0 0;}\nb {BACKGROUND-POSITION: 0 0;}"
```

but if I change the regex pattern to :-

```
var foo = new Regex("0 0 0 0", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(foo, "XXXXXXXX");
```

it does correctly change the result.

Now before you go on saying *This is a REGEX question, not a Java to C# conversion, question* I would like to make the assumption that the regex is valid because [it's being used in the following (well known/popular) project](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/CssCompressor.java) with a corresponding unit test that passes. [Another example of this code as javascript](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/ports/js/cssmin.js) has it coded like ...

```
// Replace 0 0 0 0; with 0.
css = css.replace(/:0 0 0 0(;|\})/g, ":0$1");
```

Notice the missing quotes for the first argument? So I'm wondering if i also haven't converted the java to c# properly.

Comment: The edit shows why it's useful to be able to post a short but *complete* program... then you won't have any mistakes in your posted code which aren't in your real code, because you'll have cut and paste directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your regex at the moment:

- You're not closing the bracket (or you weren't before you edited the question)
- You're searching for a string starting with ":0" whereas in `foo` there's a space after the colon

This works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string foo = "a {background-position: 0 0 0 0;}\nb "
                   + "{BACKGROUND-POSITION: 0 0;}";
        var regex = new Regex(": 0 0 0 0(;|})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string replaced = regex.Replace(foo, "XXXXXXXX");
        Console.WriteLine(replaced);
    }
}
```

I'd be surprised if the Java version *actually* worked for your original string, given the "space after colon" problem. You may want to adjust the regular expression to make the space optional:

```
": ?0 0 0 0(;|})"
```

Comment: AHH! so the error is not in the conversion, but in the css which is being used (there's a space between the colon and the first zero). hmm. strange .. because i'm assuming the unit test in the java project works fine. ... unless there's another error above (in my conversion code). Cheers Jon - much appreciated :)

Comment: oh Jon, while I have your attention. Could I step through the source java project code, like i step through .NET code.. to compare line by line outputs, while I convert the project?

Comment: @Pure.Krome, yes you can step though java code using a debugger.  All Java IDEs that I know of come with a debugger.

Comment: Cheers folks :) much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string f0o = "a {background-position: 0 0 0 1;}\nb " +
                     "{BACKGROUND-POSITION: 0 0;}";

        var regex = new Regex(": 0 0 2 0(;})", vRegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string replaced = regex.Replace(foo, "XXXXXXXX");
        Compile.WriteLine(replaced);
    }
}
```

This should fix your problem.